# Langchain Similarity search issue

Tags: vector, nlp, openai-api, langchain

We are using Chroma for storing the records in vector form. When searching the query, the return documents do not give accurate results.

```
c1 = Chroma('langchain', embedding, persist_directory)
qa = ChatVectorDBChain(vectorstore=c1, combine_docs_chain=doc_chain, question_generator=question_generator,top_k_docs_for_context=12, return_source_documents=True)*
```

What is the solution to get accurate results?

Comment: hit the same problem , I am using with redis vector db .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your chunks size and how you've prepared the knowledge base.
Sentences should be splitted properly so that when you make you vectorDB using Chroma and do semantic search it will be easy to catch the similarity. In addition, try to reduce the number of k ( returned docs ) to get the most useful part of your data not too much of them!

Hope you find this useful,

Good luck.